# How to interpret 'conflict with the Lord’s mighty devotees' thought of Satyabhama's father?

Tags: krishna, bhagavata-purana, marriage, satyabhama, inner-meaning

Most of us are aware of the Syamantaka jewel incident that leads to the marriage between Satyabhama and Krishna. The [total story](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/56/advanced-view/) is presented in Baghavatham in detail.

I wanted an in-depth understanding of the bolded portion of the following verses

> Pondering over his grievous offense and **worried about the
> possibility of conflict with the Lord’s mighty devotees**, King
> Satrājit thought, “How can I cleanse myself of my contamination, and
> how may Lord Acyuta become satisfied with me? What can I do to regain
> my good fortune and avoid being cursed by the populace for being so
> short-sighted, miserly, foolish and avaricious? I shall give my
> daughter, the jewel of all women, to the Lord, together with the
> Syamantaka jewel. That, indeed, is the only proper way to pacify Him.”
>
> [[40-42, 56: The Syamantaka Jewel,  Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam ]](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/56/40-42/)

It can be understood that Satrajit is so sad about his sin. But, what is he worried about conflict with the lord's mighty devotees? What can be the nature of conflict and who can be those mighty devotees? Are there any such instances in which Krishna's mighty devotees triggered conflict with someone?

Comment: He could probably mean tht by Jambhavant or the army of Krishna at Mathura. Since everyone knew that Krishn had defeated Jambhavant as per the blessing in Rāmavtar. And if you note Jambhavant really was a friend of Rām as well and so as wid Krishna. And when Satrajit had the jewel, Jambhavan was already defeated. Also, when Krishn can't be found (when he was battling Jambhavant), the army set of from Dwarka to find him in all directions. So, imagine who would dare to stand against so many forces.  Also, not to forget Pandavas, Devraj Indra, and many such prominent devotee kings.